# Get a VB 2008 file path relative to the published executable location

Tags: vb.net

I have a Visual Basic Studio 2008 project that I need to deploy in 3 separate server environments. Each of those environments has a different filepath for file storage, but other than that the execution of the programs will be exactly the same in all environments. 
In order to accomplish this, I'd like to instruct the program to look at a text file in the same folder as itself for the file storage file path for its environment; then i can just clone the same VB program 3 times and change the contents of the text files whenever the storage locations change. 
Before publishing an executable file, I can store the text file in the bin->debug folder and use any of the VB relative path methods that I've come across (App.Path, System.IO.getcurrentdirectory, My.Application.info.directoryPath, etc) to access it with no problem. When I publish the project, however, these find the relative path of the program as buried deep within the installed user's appdata. I want to access the text file on the server where the user goes to run the executable. 
**So my question is: how can i get the filepath of the *published* executable location?** I have searched for 4 hours and have been unsuccessful in finding an answer.
Relevant code:

```
dim fso as new scripting.filesystemobject
dim ts as scripting.textStream
ts = fso.opentextfile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\HostFiles\rootDir.txt")
rootDir = ts.ReadAll
topDir = rootDir & 'rest of file storage location
```

Comment: VB.NET and VB6 are two different languages and, as a consequence, the solution for your problem could be really different. Use only the relevant TAG

Comment: I think it is VB.NET (My.Application), which means there is no reason for `scripting.filesystemobject`. <- @Steve.  You dont really want to get a path relative to the installed folder - look in Program Files and see how many apps have data there.  Your app will likely not have rights to perform IO there.  Use My Documents or a Users folder - thats why they are there

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure what you mean by 'Your app will likely not have rights to perform IO there.' Where? Do you mean on my server?

Comment: Steve- I tagged it with both because I'm using VB 2008, which allows includes from VB.NET. See below. Would appreciate removal of the downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this if you are using VB.Net:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Eg:

```
Dim strContent As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\HostFiles\rootDir.txt")
```

Comment: I tried this already. It led me to the location deep within user appdata. Is this supposed to access the executable's published location?

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web application in ASP.Net(using VB) ? I believe the `Application.StartupPath` should give the location from which the EXE was started. So it should be pointed to the location of the EXE file.

Comment: Desktop application. But I tried Application.StartupPath and it pointed to the exe file installed deep within the user's appdata, while I need it to point to the exe file that I published to the server.